# SQL Server 2012 How to change the data type of a column from bit to datefield?

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2012, bit, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

I have a table `Person` with a column called `onvacation`.
This column is of data type `bit` since it's a boolean in the code. It has values null, 0 and 1.

I would like to change the data type of this column from `bit` to `datetime` so that all values that are 1, are converted to a new date (could be current date). and 0 and null values would both be just null.

I tried following w3bschool's tutorial and did a query:

```
ALTER TABLE Person ALTER COLUMN onvacation datetime
```

But that gives an error `'DF____Person__onvac__59062A42' is dependent on column 'onvacation'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get this error because **`DF____Person__onvac__59062A42`**  sql object Depends on **`onvacation`** column.

You can Find Dependency of Person  table by **Right Click-->View Dependancy**

remove that dependent  object and try to alter column